# Windows 7 taskbar tweak - make Alt-Tab in Windows 7 like Ctrl-Tab in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, taskbar

1. Assume that we have three tabs in Firefox, and we are at the first tab,
   when we do `Ctrl Tab`, we navigate to the second tab, `Ctrl-Tab` again,
   we go to the third tab (1st >> 2nd >> 3rd). We must do
   `Ctrl-Shift-Tab` to navigate back (3rd >> 2nd >> 1st)
2. Now assume we have three windows in the Windows 7 taskbar, and we are at the first
   window. We do `Alt Tab`, we navigate to the second window, `Alt Tab`
   again, and we back to the first window, **not the third window**.

How can I make the Windows 7 taskbar like the Firefox tab bar? All windows stand permanently in the order I made when I opened them, then I can navigate between them **without** looking into this thumbnail.

---

Finally, I gave up, can't find any idea to do this on GOOGLE.
I'm stick with `Window key` + `numeric key` (in Win7)

[image: Win7 Alt-Tab thumbnail]

Comment: You *can* do the reverse: make FF's ctrl-tab work like Windows based on most recently used ordering. I do this with the option that the Tab Mix Plus extension adds.

Comment: Thanks Richard but I the way `Ctrl Tab` in Firefox work is more logical when I work with multiple (>=3 window/tab) as the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Windows lists its windows in their Z-order, that is the topmost first, the bottommost last. When using Alt-Tab once, the window just below the topmost window is bring topmost, while the previous topmost is put just below. The previously selected windows will thus be the target of the next Alt-Tab.

Note that the order the windows are presented after each Tab pressure is not related to the  position in the task bar, only to the Z-order. I'm not aware of way to change this behavior.

You must find a way to affect the Z-order to recreate the tab switching scheme within a multi document window.

Answer (score 0):

`Win+T` switches through the apps in the taskbar in the order that they are displayed there. (not their z-order)